# Understand a complex code base using a sequence diagram

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sequence-diagram, codebase

I am  working on a big project with a complex codebase written in java. I want to understand a particular piece of code and i thought getting a sequence diagram of the entry point method would give me a good idea. I use intelliJ and i looked for a plugin which could do this and i found 'SequencePlugin' but unfortunately it is not working in intelliJ 8.1.4. Can i achieve what i am trying to in any other way? Is there a standard approach to follow when trying to understand a complex codebase other than by debugging?

Comment: There is a vast amount of plugins available for eclipse. Might be worth considering to change to eclipse, be it just for understanding the code.

Comment: Or at least upgrade Intellij.  Version 12 is out..

Comment: @DanielS, thanks, i would consider that

Comment: @PaulHicks thanks, i could do that, but i doubt whether it would be of any use.

Comment: Why dont you upgrade to a more recent version of intellij and try this one: http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6134?pr=idea. Not sure if it works in v12 or v13, but a comment says it does in v11.

Comment: @DanielS. are you serious, move from intellij to eclipse? lol... that's like selling your ferarri to buy a toyota.